# Integration of IBM Rhapsody with IAR Workbench using the property (.prp) files

Tags: integration, rhapsody

I want to integrate IBM Rhapsody with IAR Workbench so that, I will be  able to use the Code generated in Rhapsody with the compilers of IAR. One way I found was using the .prp files of Rhapsody. I am unaware of using the .prp files.

Answer (score 0):

There is a (not very informative) manual on adapting Rhapsody. (Try searching "adapter" in the Rhapsody help.)
You are very scarce with information however, adapting your Rhapsody to use a certain compiler depends on a lot more then just the compiler.
Do you want to use C or C++? What RTOS are you using? What CPU do you use (IAR makes compilers for many CPU's)
You can also check, there are companies that deliver turn-key adapters for Rhapsody.

Walter

Answer (score 0):

Rhapsody supports workflow and platform integration with Eclipse. IAR Workbench also has Eclipse plugin.

You can start by installing Rhapsody Workflow integration plugin in your Eclipse, create Eclipse configuration in Rhapsody and generate code for this configuration.

This way you will also create Eclipse project. Try to build that project to discover what should be modified. The project should include paths, Rhapsody Framework's missing libraries, etc.

From this point on you can ask more specific questions regarding Rhapsody customization. `.prp` files are only one of possible ways.

BTW, which Rhapsody framework and language do you want to use? There are

- OXF C++
- SXFC++
- OXF C
- MXf C
- SMXF C